# Change text width in a specific part of a chapter or section

Tags: paragraphs, width, text

I'm new to Latex and was wondering if it'd be possible to change the text width for a paragraph without changing it for the whole document. Thank you.

Comment: `\begin{quote} narrow stuff here \end{quote}`

Comment: It doesn't work with \begin{quote} narrow stuff here \end{quote}
How can I specify the width I want?